# Use Kubernetes RBAC namespace roles?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to give a service account my-service-account access to apply deployments within a namespace my-namespace in a Google Kubernetes Engine cluster running Kubernetes 1.14.

This is what my rolebinding looks like:

```
$ kubectl describe rolebinding -n my-namespace --context my-cluster
Name:         my-namespace-service-account-policy
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
  Kind:  Role
  Name:  edit
Subjects:
  Kind            Name                                 Namespace
  ----            ----                                 ---------
  ServiceAccount  my-service-account                   my-namespace
```

However, when my service account goes to apply a manifest, I get an error that ends with:

```
deployments.apps "my-namespace" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:my-namespace:my-service-account" cannot get resource "deployments" in API group "apps" in the namespace "my-namespace": RBAC: role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "edit" not found
```

I also tried using "admin" instead of edit. If I instead create a clusterrolebinding with cluster-admin for the same service account, it works fine. How do I grant the account access just to the namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [predefined `edit` name](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.14.0/plugin/pkg/auth/authorizer/rbac/bootstrappolicy/policy.go#L238) is a `ClusterRole`, and thus making reference to it as a `Role` is not referring to the same entity.

The godoc for that declaration seems to imply that it's safe to create the `ClusterRoleBinding` to the `edit` `ClusterRole` since it is scoped to namespace-level editing, but I haven't studied that policy extensively and am not an RBAC wizard

Comment: Creating a rolebinding with --clusterrole seems to work:

kubectl create rolebinding $rolebinding --namespace $namespace --clusterrole=admin --serviceaccount "${namespace}:${deploymentAccountName}" --context $k8sContext